# Why is Web consuming all of my Raspberry Pi's CPU?

Tags: raspbian, web

I understand that the [Web/Epiphany browser is in beta](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/5535), but why does it cause Raspbian to stuggle just loading Google, or any other website (with only one tab open)?

Midori doesn't have this problem, and Web's features contradict this:

> - A good multi-tab experience
> - ARMv6-optimized 2d rendering
> - Accelerated image and HTML5 video decoding

I have enabled [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) with:

```
cgroup_enable=memory
```

How can I make Web run faster?

Comment: Never mind, just re-read your post and saw that you were, in fact, talking about the beta.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Yeah, your deleted post looks well formatted though!

Comment: Mine workd fine, even faster than midori. Are you using 256mb or 512mb ram version?

Comment: @mrpi64 256 MB.

Comment: Could be because it's in beta.

Comment: That might be the problem, having a 256. I have 512 and it runs BETTER than midori.

Answer (score 1):

The raspberry pi struggles to run web browsers and the experience of web browsing is not very good. If the browser doesn't work well for you, you can always switch to better alternatives like netsurf,etc,etc. Makeuseof even wrote an article on it
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-choose-and-optimise-your-raspberry-pi-browser/
hope this helps you!

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. If you could post a synopsis of what is on that page, it would make your answer better and would help keep this site more informative and usable, even if link rot does occur. Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

Raspberry Pi is not designed for we browsing, and therefore you will never get a very fast solution. I would suggest trying midori, the default browser. Your browser is probably to big.